# Navigate to an external URL for login credential verification?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC ASP .NET application that needs to verify whether the user that is logged in is currently an active user or not. The issue is that I don't have this info on my machine.
In order to check for the active/inactive bit, it seems that I have to go to an XML view, somewhere on the web, which also requires a login (from me).

Is it feasible to do the following in C#:

For each user logging in to my application:

- Go to a specific URL
- Login
- Search the XML view to see if user is active
- Return to my application with the result

Whitelisting the IP to skip Login wasn't an option according to IT.

Comment: You should have a look at client certificate authentication, a common method for server to server communication.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and indeed asked many times - adding "web scraping" to your search would likely give you many duplicates. (Client cert solution suggested by @FrodeNilsen is significantly easier than trying to automate sign in, but it is very different approach)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will search for "web scraping". @FrodeNilsen I'm not sure why, but the IT team is kinda pushing me in this direction.